# Change all values of a column at once

Tags: google-sheets

How can I change all values of column A (currently empty) to be 5?

In Excel, I could do Paste Special > Add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am confused by your explanation of how you do it in excel (past special then multiply) this will multiply all the values in the column by the value you are trying to paste. In your example you said that column A is empty. That will leave you with a column of zeros.

So here is my approaches:

- If you have the value in the top row, then <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will copy the value down the rest of the selected cells.
- If the value you want is on the clipboard - then select the cells you want to paste into and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or use paste special - paste values only.